# Artifactory AQL not working with relative time parameters

Tags: artifactory, aql, artifactory-query-lang

This below AQL query works fine and gives me expected results but when I use time relateive time parameters as 2W 5d getting a 400 bad request.

```
items.find(
  {

    "repo": "test-repo",
    "name" :{"$match": "*.13.4.*.*.nupkg"},
    "created" : {"$lte" : "2016-11-11"}
  }
)

.sort({"$desc":["created"]})
.offset(20)
```

400 bad request with below query

```
items.find(
  {

    "repo": "test-repo",
    "name" :{"$match": "*.13.4.1.*.nupkg"},
    "created" : {"$last" : "3d"}
  }
)
```

I get the error as

)
, it looks like there is syntax error near the following sub-query: $last" : "3d"}
  }
)

Also is there any way to use current date as a parameter instead of passing the date everytime? 
Please advise.

Comment: Can you post what's in the Artifactory log when you try to execute this query?

Comment: @fundeldman This below is the error I get in artifactory.log. If its any helpful                                                                                                              2016-11-16 15:40:25,566 [http-nio-8081-exec-3] [ERROR] (o.a.r.r.a.AqlResource:80) - Fail to parse query: items.find(
  {

    "repo": "test-repo",
    "name" :{"$match": "*.13.4.1.*.nupkg"},
    "created" : {"$last" : "3d"}
  }
):